# Solve Heat Equation using Fourier Transform (non homogeneous)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, heat-equation, integral-transforms

I know how to solve heat equation where it's like $u_t=k\cdot u_{xx}$ (using Fourier Transform or using Separation of Variables) but this exercise is really difficult for me.

I have this:

$$u_t(x,t)=k \cdot u_{xx}(x,t)-a\cdot k \cdot u(x,t)$$
$$u_x(0,t)=0$$
$$u(x,0) = f(x)$$

with $x>0, t>0$ and $a, k$ are positive constants.

I have to find $u(x,t)$ and propose a possible $f(x)$

Any help? Thanks

I was told I cannot use Fourier Transform, I have to use Fourier Cosine Transform, and I don't know why

Comment: You can bring the equation to the form you know how to solve with a simple change of variables. Define $v = u e^{ak t}$ then $v_t = k v_{xx}$ with $v_x(0,t) = 0$ and $v(x,0) = f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this problem should be solved with Fourier cosine transform rather than Fourier transform. If you use Fourier transform, you won't be able to take the b.c. at $x=0$ into consideration, and the equation will then be solved in $-\infty<x<\infty$ with implicit b.c.s at $\pm\infty$. (For this part check [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2084704/58219) for more information. )

The key point is, when $f(\infty)=0$, Fourier cosine transform

$$
\mathcal{F}_t^{(c)}[f(t)](\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\int _0^{\infty } f(t) \cos  (\omega t) d t
$$

has the following property:

$$
\mathcal{F}_t^{(c)}\left[f''(t)\right](\omega)=-\omega^2 \mathcal{F}_t^{(c)}[f(t)](\omega)-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} f'(0)
$$

You can easily verify this property using integration by parts.

So, by applying this property on your equation, we have

$$
\mathcal{F}_x^{(c)}\left[u^{(1,0)}(t,x)\right](\omega )=k \left(-\omega ^2 \mathcal{F}_x^{(c)}[u(t,x)](\omega )-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} u^{(0,1)}(t,0)\right)-a k \mathcal{F}_x^{(c)}[u(t,x)](\omega )
$$

Substitute the b.c. into the equation, we obtain a simple initial value problem (IVP) of linear ODE:

$$U'(t)=-a k U(t)-k \omega ^2 U(t)$$
$$U(0)=F$$

where $U(t)=\mathcal{F}_x^{(c)}[u(t,x)](\omega )$, $F=\mathcal{F}_x^{(c)}[f(x)](\omega)$.

If you have difficulty in solving the IVP, check the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation)). Anyway, we can easily find its solution:

$$U(t)=F e^{-k t \left(a + \omega ^2\right)}$$

The last step is to transform back with inverse Fourier Cosine transform

$${\mathcal{F}_\omega^{(c)}}^{-1}[F(\omega)](t)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \int_0^{\infty } F(\omega ) \cos (t \omega) \, d\omega $$

and the solution is

$$
u(t,x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \int_0^{\infty } e^{-k t \left(a + \omega ^2\right)} \mathcal{F}_x^{(c)}[f(x)](\omega ) \cos (\omega  t) \, d\omega
$$

Notice this solution is probably the same as the one [given by doraemonpaul](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1490188/58219). I guess he has just chosen a different convention for Fourier parameters.

Comment: Can you explain what do the notations $u^{(1,0)}\,(t,x)$ and $u^{(0,1)}\,(t,0)$ mean? I am really confused with them.

Comment: @sam $u^{(0,1)}(t,0)$ is equivalent to $\frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial x}\big|_{x=0}$.

Comment: I see, thank you. But I still don't know why we can't use Fourier Transform and why we have to use Fourier Cosine Transform. Can you explain the reason? Thanks.

Comment: @sam As already mentioned above, if we use Fourier transform, we won't be able to take the b.c. at $x=0$ into consideration, and the equation will then be solved in $-\infty<x<\infty$ with implicit b.c.s at $\pm\infty$. (_Usually_ it's $f(\pm ∞)=0$. )

Comment: @sam BTW here is another example solving PDE with Fourier cosine transform: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158079/1871

Comment: Yea I saw that. But in order to use Fourier Cosine Transform, we will also need the implicit b.c. at $+\infty$ (i.e. $f(+\infty)=0$) right? In this problem, this necessary condition to use Fourier Cosine Transform would be $u(+\infty,t)=0$ for all $t\gt 0.$ But we don't have this extra condition.

Comment: I mean, if you want to use integration by parts to calculate the Fourier Cosine Transform of $u_{xx}$ , then you will have to have the condition that $u(+\infty,t)=c$ for all $t\gt 0$ and some constant $c$. But here we don't have such condition.

Comment: @sam Yes, the statement is not rigorous enough. Well, I would blame it on…Er… the looseness of the whole mathematical physics equation subject. Such kind of stuff is just everywhere. For example, if you check those materials about solving PDE using Fourier transform, you'll see the statement about b.c. at $\pm \infty$ is often missing, too.

Comment: Yea, but I think @doraemonpaul 's post didn't use the b.c. at $\pm \infty$. I feel like it makes more sense.

Comment: @SamWong Then why is separation of variables, which is rather counterintuitive, a valid method?

Answer (score 1):

Of course use separation of variables:

Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ ,

Then $X(x)T'(t)=kX''(x)T(t)-akX(x)T(t)$

$X(x)(T'(t)+akT(t))=kX''(x)T(t)$

$\dfrac{T'(t)+akT(t)}{kT(t)}=\dfrac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-s^2$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=-k(s^2+a)\\X''(x)+s^2X(x)=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}T(t)=c_3(s)e^{-kt(s^2+a)}\\X(x)=\begin{cases}c_1(s)\sin xs+c_2(s)\cos xs&\text{when}~s\neq0\\c_1x+c_2&\text{when}~s=0\end{cases}\end{cases}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-kt(s^2+a)}\sin xs~ds+\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-kt(s^2+a)}\cos xs~ds$

$u_x(x,t)=\int_0^\infty sC_1(s)e^{-kt(s^2+a)}\cos xs~ds-\int_0^\infty sC_2(s)e^{-kt(s^2+a)}\sin xs~ds$

$u_x(0,t)=0$ :

$\int_0^\infty sC_1(s)e^{-kt(s^2+a)}~ds=0$

$C_1(s)=0$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-kt(s^2+a)}\cos xs~ds$

$u(x,0)=f(x)$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_2(s)\cos xs~ds=f(x)$

$\mathcal{F}_{c,s\to x}\{C_2(s)\}=f(x)$

$C_2(s)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{c,x\to s}\{f(x)\}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{c,x\to s}\{f(x)\}e^{-kt(s^2+a)}\cos xs~ds$

Comment: Though the method is not Fourier transform, the answer is correct, I think. I suggest you to mention the convention of Fourier parameters in your answer. (It's different from the one chosen in my answer, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Let us apply the Fourier Transform with respect to the spatial coordinate $x$
  :$$\partial_{t}\hat{u}\left(\xi,t\right)=-k\xi^{2}\hat{u}\left(\xi,t\right)-iak\xi\hat{u}\left(\xi,t\right)$$
 i.e. $$\partial_{t}\hat{u}\left(\xi,t\right)=-k\left(\xi^{2}-ia\xi\right)\hat{u}\left(\xi,t\right)$$
 hence$$\hat{u}\left(\xi,t\right)=Ce^{-k\left(\xi^{2}-ia\xi\right)t}$$
 where $C$
  is a constant to be determinated later. Here the convention used for the Fourier transform is$$\hat{u}\left(\xi,t\right)=\mathrm{TF}\left[u\right]\left(\xi,t\right)=\intop_{x\in\mathbb{R}}u\left(x,t\right)e^{-ix\xi}dx.$$
 Now I let you come back to the initial space with the inversion formula$$u\left(x,t\right)=\mathrm{TF}^{-1}\left[\hat{u}\right]\left(x,t\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\intop_{x\in\mathbb{R}}Ce^{-k\left(\xi^{2}-ia\xi\right)t}e^{ix\xi}d\xi$$
 (take care to the sign in the exponential). You must find a gaussian function.

Comment: How do I know if it's better to use Fourier Transform or Fourier Cosine Transform or Fourier Sine Transform?

Comment: For some parity reasons I guess : if you integrate an odd function on $\mathbb{R}$, then you integral (taken over all $\mathbb{R}$) is zero.

Comment: that's true, but I don't know why my professor used fourier cosine transform

Comment: I was told I cannot use Fourier Transform, I have to use Fourier Cosine Transform, and I don't know why

Comment: can you help me?